# Does .NET File.Move copy and then delete

Tags: c#-4.0

Up to now when I have to move files across shares I use code like below:

- Copy file to target using File.Copy method
- Check if file is successfully copied by using File.Exists
- Delete the source

I have used the above process because I thought that you could not use File.Move to move files across shares or volumes. After digging a bit today I realised that you can do that so my next concern was how are failures handled i.e. does the underlying .NET code actually copy and then delete the files?

I checked for the File.Move code at [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs#47c527ad52ea10da) and see that it actually calls the windows MoveFile API.

So my question is, can I safely used File.Move to move files across UNC paths?

Comment: Of course, operating system functions were not designed to destroy user data when they fail.  MoveFile already implements your bullet list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be wrong, but it seems that you do get delete-after-copy semantics.

`MoveFile` says that

> To specify how to move the file, use the `MoveFileEx` or
>   `MoveFileWithProgress` function. To perform this operation as a
>   transacted operation, use the `MoveFileTransacted` function.

This implies that `MoveFile` does not provide either transaction semantics or guarantees as to "how the file is moved" (and there is nothing else in the documentation that refers to such).

[`MoveFileEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), on the other hand, states that

> When moving a file, the destination can be on a different file system
>   or volume. If the destination is on another drive, you must set the
>   `MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED` flag in `dwFlags`.

The effect of [`MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#movefile_copy_allowed) is

> If the file is to be moved to a different volume, the function
>   simulates the move by using the `CopyFile` and `DeleteFile` functions. If
>   the file is successfully copied to a different volume and the original
>   file is unable to be deleted, the function succeeds leaving the source
>   file intact.

The way I interpret this is that since `MoveFileEx` does not give you the option of doing things otherwise when moving across volumes, it stands to reason that `MoveFile` also works in that mode as well.

In addition, moving across volumes means possibly moving across filesystems and even machines (especially when using UNC paths). In this situation there is no way to place the file in its destination path other than incrementally copying its contents, which seems to pretty much guarantee that the operation will be a delete-after-copy.